# How to iteratively match word sequences

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have strings like these:

```
test <- c("oh i mean well i do n't know well he 's like oh",
          "yeah so well he did n't say oh he said f** well you know what he 's like",
          "oh you know well why well maybe he thought oh well good", 
          "oh my god well what the hell did he oh you know")
```

I'd like to match all word sequences starting with `oh` and ending with `well` and, the inverse, starting with `well` and ending with `oh`. This use of `str_extract_all` does match some of the target sequences but not all, because it is unable to **iteratively** match, that is, it does not start anew from each `oh` or `well` once it has consumed it in a match:

```
library(stringr)
strings <- unlist(str_extract_all(test, "\\boh\\b.*?\\bwell\\b|\\bwell\\b.*?\\boh\\b"))
[1] "oh i mean well"           "well he 's like oh"       "well he did n't say oh"   "oh you know well"        
[5] "well maybe he thought oh" "oh my god well"
```

The complete output would be this:

```
[1] "oh i mean well"     "well he 's like oh"     "well he did n't say oh"     "oh he said f** well" 
[5] "oh you know well"  "oh well"   "well maybe he thought oh"     "oh my god well"
[9] "well what the hell did he oh"
```

Comment: How about: `c(unlist(str_extract_all(test, "\\boh\\b.*?\\bwell\\b")), unlist(str_extract_all(test, "\\bwell\\b.*?\\boh\\b")))` ?

Comment: Can you break it into two regex?..i.e. `c(unlist(str_extract_all(test, "\\boh\\b.*?\\bwell\\b")), unlist(str_extract_all(test, "\\bwell\\b.*?\\boh\\b")))`

Comment: Use non-consuming lookaround clusters instead. For the first side of alternation it would be `(?<=\\boh\\b).*?(?=\\bwell\\b)`

Comment: How come you expect `well you know what he 's like`? There is no `oh` at the end. Also, do you mean to say there must be no `well` and `oh` in between the `well/oh` and `oh/well`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point, well observed. Have changed the expected output

Comment: @GKi :your solution does the trick! Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Sotos :your solution does the trick! Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: I will let @GKi do it as he posted a minute earlier :)

Comment: @Sotos That's graceful!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Please check the expected output.  I do not think the first two comments provide the solution you need if the task is to match the shortest substring between the two words. You can't just use `.*?` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `stringr::str_match_all` solution (because `stringr::str_extract_all` "loses" all captured substrings):

```
test <- c("oh i mean well i do n't know well he 's like oh",
"yeah so well he did n't say oh he said f** well you know what he 's like", 
"oh you know well why well maybe he thought oh well good",
"oh my god well what the hell did he oh you know")
res <- stringr::str_match_all(test, "(?=(\\boh\\b(?:(?!\\boh\\b).)*?\\bwell\\b|\\bwell\\b(?:(?!\\bwell\\b).)*?\\boh\\b))")

unlist(lapply(res, function(x) x[,-1]))
```

See an [R demo online](https://tio.run/##TVDRbsMgDHzPV3i8FKJ00l6jTfmQdapoQmtUAlUgSpH275ndNOle4M6@OxuGeU4mJvjcQytFQLDQG@1hMs4R7gL4XYKrD9NSQgO7CM5eDQQUVSGy0QgxbN3Odg9L1JkUXImaSueyXCQ5jM841OlfnKig4PmvPqsnzAvodT4ZlicM4wUTZz8alxA63oN4n4l1q5HSE7KFGC@FvPEWL1QxmMjPjmmw/jLUNYFjr1OLR@2c5F@pQMjmSx4Op4B0yKaWzdvK1LsqG7p5HF2/L7jpnnxVLjZFo4vROxuTdPp2c1nSJhWcR98mG7y8K7h/V/uPH6WKef4D) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU2prZ/2).

**Details**

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead:

  - `(` - start of a capturing group:

    - `\boh\b(?:(?!\boh\b).)*?\bwell\b` - `oh` whole word and then any 0+ chars, as few as possible that do not start a whole word `oh` up to the leftmost `well` whole word
    - `|` - or
    - `\bwell\b(?:(?!\bwell\b).)*?\boh\b` - `well` whole word and then any 0+ chars, as few as possible that do not start a whole word `well` up to the leftmost `oh` whole word
  - `)` - end of the capturing group
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead.

Output:

```
[1] "oh i mean well"               "well he 's like oh"          
[3] "well he did n't say oh"       "oh he said f** well"         
[5] "oh you know well"             "well maybe he thought oh"    
[7] "oh well"                      "oh my god well"              
[9] "well what the hell did he oh"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. One question if you don't mind: I never know what the meaning is of `(?:` - what is it?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `(?:...)` is a **[non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/)** used to group a sequence of patterns (to use alternatives, or quantify it) without storing the text captured in a separate memory slot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_extract_all` one for `oh...well` and one for `well...oh` using your regex:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(c(str_extract_all(test, "\\boh\\b.*?\\bwell\\b")
       , str_extract_all(test, "\\bwell\\b.*?\\boh\\b")))
#[1] "oh i mean well"                       
#[2] "oh he said f** well"                  
#[3] "oh you know well"                     
#[4] "oh well"                              
#[5] "oh my god well"                       
#[6] "well i do n't know well he 's like oh"
#[7] "well he did n't say oh"               
#[8] "well why well maybe he thought oh"    
#[9] "well what the hell did he oh"
```

or in case the shortest sequence:

```
unlist(c(str_extract_all(test, "\\boh\\b((?!\\boh\\b).)*?\\bwell\\b")
 , str_extract_all(test, "\\bwell\\b((?!\\bwell\\b).)*?\\boh\\b")))
#[1] "oh i mean well"               "oh he said f** well"         
#[3] "oh you know well"             "oh well"                     
#[5] "oh my god well"               "well he 's like oh"          
#[7] "well he did n't say oh"       "well maybe he thought oh"    
#[9] "well what the hell did he oh"
```

Data:

```
test <- c("oh i mean well i do n't know well he 's like oh",
          "yeah so well he did n't say oh he said f** well you know what he 's like",
          "oh you know well why well maybe he thought oh well good", 
          "oh my god well what the hell did he oh you know")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've never been so torn as to which answer to accept but have ultimately decided to accept @Wiktor's answer as it provides yet more insight into regex.